# Need regular expression for checking at least 3 uppercase, 3 lowercase, 3 digits and 3 special character

Tags: regex

Need regular expression for checking at least 3 uppercase, 3 lowercase, 3 digits and 3 special character any where in string.

I have tried `/^(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]{3,})(?=.*[A-Z]{3,})(?=.*\d{3,})(?=.*[0-9]{3,}).+/`
but this checking contiguous string like :: `abcABC123(*)` but did not check like: `1a(2b)AB*3cC`

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but if this is for a password regex then I would strongly suggest that you make it less annoying - 3 of all of those characters would drive most people round the bend.

Comment: Don't use a regular expression for this. As you can see, a simple English description leads to an impenetrable regex. I'm sure whatever programming language you're using lets you write something easier to maintain. Like say "matches(password, /[a-z]/) >= 3 && matches(password, /[A-Z]/) >= 3 && matches(password, /[0-9]/) >= 3 && matches(password, /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/) >= 3" (just making up syntax but you get the idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(?=(.*[^A-Za-z0-9]){3,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){3,})(?=(.*\d){3,})(?=.*[a-z]){3,}).+/
```

So you were close.

Answer (score 6):

You were close: you need to bracket the `.*` with the character classes in your look aheads:

```
^(?=(.*[^A-Za-z0-9]){3})(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})(?=(.*\d){3}).+
```

The reason this works is that the character types may not be adjacent, eg 3 digits might be `a1b2c3`, hence the `.*` to allow other intervening character types.

Note that you don't need the open-ended quantifiers. eg `(.*\d){3}` is sufficient to assert that there are at least 3 digits - ie not `...{3,}`

---

And a final note: those leading/trailing slashes have nothing whatsoever to do with regular expressions - they are an application language artefact. It makes questions and answers clearer and more useful to more people if they are omitted.

Comment: The slashes make it easier to see leading and trailing whitespace. For the same reason, it is conventional to put strings in quotation marks. Also, the `.*`s should be `[^a-z]*` etc. to avoid n^2 backtracking.

Comment: @RaymondChen Lots of languages don't use slashes though, eg java, so novice programmers (who frequent this site) may attempt to use the slashes in the regex and be confused. It's good to be helpful to as many people as possible. Regarding the visible whitespace, that is not an advantage on this site if code is marked up properly (as it usually is) and besides, I can't ever recall putting a space character at the start or end of a regex.

Comment: Do you put quotation marks around strings? Not all languages use quotation marks to delimit strings.

Comment: @RaymondChen If the String is in code, and the language of the question is (for example) java, then yes, but if it's just a sequence of characters then I just use markdown (indent by 4 spaces) to show the characters clearly. I'm not backing down on the slashes thing btw. They really are not regex delimiters any more than quotes are. Eg in a java regex question, I don't use quotes there, eg `"some regex"`, I just show it as I did here, ie `some regex`. The language delimiters are not part of the answer/question when the subject is regex

Answer (score 2):

Both of the other answers fail for a string which doesn't match the "at least 3 lowercase" requirement.  Using Bohemian's answer but supporting that case gives the following regex:

`^(?=(.*[^A-Za-z0-9]){3})(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})(?=(.*[a-z]){3})(?=(.*\d){3}).+`