# Regular expression to check 3 uppercase ,3 digits, 3 special chars

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression that checks whether a string has 3 uppercase lettrs,3 digits and 3 special characters(&%#@!$) in anywhere. Those letters need not to be one after the other.also length of the string should at least 10. also there should not be any spaces.

So that string

```
aF2$Rec45yT&! - will match
aF2$Re c45yT&! - will not match
F2$R45T&!      - will not match
```

Comment: Voting to reopen because requirements of dupe linked question are not same as this one and that accepted answer is code only answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need regular expression for checking at least 3 uppercase, 3 lowercase, 3 digits and 3 special character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689167/need-regular-expression-for-checking-at-least-3-uppercase-3-lowercase-3-digits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex fits the requirements:

```
^(?=(.*?[A-Z]){3})(?=(.*?[0-9]){3})(?=(.*?[&%#@!$]){3})\S{10,}$
```

Components are:

```
(?=(.*?[A-Z]){3})    - lookahead to make sure there are at least 3 upper case letters
(?=(.*?[0-9]){3})    - lookahead to make sure there are at least 3 digits
(?=(.*?[&%#@!$]){3}) - lookahead to make sure there are at least 3 of the listed special characters
\S{10,}              - to make sure there is no space in input and it is at least 10 in lenght
```

Comment: Why the `?` after `.*` ?

Comment: @dystroy: `.*` might also work but I just keep it non-greedy `.*?` to be doubly sure to not match unwanted text.

Comment: Both would probably work the same but I wonder if the ? might make a faster regex.

Comment: Yes my sense is same that `.*?` might perform better but haven't yet run any benchmarks on this.

Comment: Sorry dude... I found some bug.. I thought it with the regex so thats why I removed it and was going to ask your help again. So i removed the acceptance mark. But later I found it's due to a typo. But forget to add the mark again.