# Regex match group at least n times or not at all, in random order with other matching groups

Tags: java, regex

I am working with java regexes, but I guess the principles apply for every regex.

I have these requirements for the segment a regex should match:

- have at least 3 times 'a'
- have at least 3 times 'b'
- occurrences of 'a' and 'b' can be in any order

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689167/need-regular-expression-for-checking-at-least-3-uppercase-3-lowercase-3-digits) I came up with the following regex ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qLU5pR/1)):

```
(?=([b]*[a]){3})(?=([a]*[b]){3})[ab]+
```

I am struggling with adding a new requirement:

- Match if there is no or at least 3 'c'
- as above, 'c' can occur anywhere in the segment

Examples for valid sequences:

```
aaabbb
ababab
aaabbbccc
abcabcabc
ababcabcc
```

Examples for invalid sequences (as a whole):

```
aaabbbc
aabbb
abbccc
abcabca
```

My thoughts so far:

- Having at least 3 'c'

  `(?=([bc]*[a]){3})(?=([ac]*[b]){3})(?=([ab]*[c]){3,})[abc]+`
- Combining this and above solution in a crude manner ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SJoBhB/3)) which basically just a large "either none or at least 3"

  `((?=([bc]*[a]){3})(?=([ac]*[b]){3})(?=([ab]*[c]){3,})[abc]+|(?=([b]*[a]){3})(?=([a]*[b]){3})[ab]+)`

Finally the **Question**: Is there a better way to achieve this using other methods, like or-ing the 'c'-requirement look-ahead, nested look-aheads or something entirely different?

Comment: One of those questions, that's really fun to fiddle about with!  Many good answers already, won't put another one. I came up with a [similar one](https://regex101.com/r/snJokh/1) and also a [negative variant](https://regex101.com/r/6GajTr/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble: very nice negative variant.

Comment: @bobblebubble Nice! The first one [fails for the no-'c' part](https://regex101.com/r/8oKI3S/1) (after removing the ^$) when appending whitespace. And as expected, the second one [fails for the 'c'-part](https://regex101.com/r/mp3MEG/1) also when appending whitespace.

I do not understand why though, I was unable to fix them..

Comment: @TheCenturyNoob Yes of yourse. `^` matches the start and `$` end of string. If you want to match that like words, use *word boundaries `\b`*: [update 1](https://regex101.com/r/4xHdmG/1) and [update 2](https://regex101.com/r/QOI26K/1) (update 1 also needed to change the *quantifier* in `[ab]*\b` to `+` for *one or more*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<![abc])              # No "a", "b", "c" allowed immediately on the left
(?=(?:[bc]*a){3})       # At least three "a"s
(?=(?:[ac]*b){3})       # At least three "b"s
(?:                     # Either
   (?=[ab]*(?![abc]))   #  only "a" or "b"s allowed until a location not followed with "a", "b" or "c"
 |                      #  or
   (?=(?:[ab]*c){3})    # At least three "c"s
)
[abc]+                  # Match and consume one or more "a", "b" or "c" chars
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TStrIl/3).

As a single line:

```
(?<![abc])(?=(?:[bc]*a){3})(?=(?:[ac]*b){3})(?:(?=[ab]*(?![abc]))|(?=(?:[ab]*c){3}))[abc]+
```

Comment: It provides a good solution for the hidden real use case of this regex: [trying to match base64 encoded data strings without over-eagerly matching variable assignments](https://regex101.com/r/5l1aVQ/1). I know it's a bad idea... ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could assert 3 times `a` and 3 times `b`, and then optionally match at least 3 times a `c`

Add anchors `^` and `$` to assert the start and the end of the string.

Note that you don't have to put a single char like `[a]` in a character class:

```
^(?=([bc]*a){3})(?=([ca]*b){3})[ab]*(?:c[ab]*c[ab]*c[abc]*)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=([bc]*a){3})` Assert 3 times an `a` char
- `(?=([ca]*b){3})` Assert 3 times a `b` char
- `[ab]*` Match optional chars `a` `b`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `c[ab]*c[ab]*c` Match 3 times a `c` char
  - `[abc]*` Match optional `a`,`b` and `c` chars
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1S9s9F/1)

As you don't really need the capture groups, you can use non capture groups `(?:` instead for the repetition:

```
^(?=(?:[bc]*a){3})(?=(?:[ca]*b){3})[ab]*(?:c[ab]*c[ab]*c[abc]*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RKqipr/1)

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you! Let's assume for a second that I want to match in-sequence so we can discard the string start- and end-tags (^$). According to regex101 matching [the first](https://regex101.com/r/6Sx7DI/2) as well as [the second](https://regex101.com/r/xtF2BE/2) produce interesting results for the sequence "babcbaba" though and I am not entirely sure why.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?=^(?:.*a){3}.*$)(?=^(?:.*b){3}.*$)(?=^(?:.*c){3}.*$|^[^c]*$).*
```

##### Short Explanation

- `(?=^(?:.*a){3}.*$)` Assert that string contains at least 3 `a`
- `(?=^(?:.*b){3}.*$)` Assert that string contains at least 3 `b`
- `(?=^(?:.*c){3}.*$|^[^c]*$)` Assert that string contains at least 3 `c` or the string does not contain any `c`
- `.*` Match the whole string that passes all assertions

Also, see the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/n699Sm/2) and [Java example](https://regex101.com/r/n699Sm/2/codegen?language=java)

Comment: Thanks for the interestsing answer! I like the part where c is excluded (it taught me something), but there are two issues: The regex is too permissive of other characters like whitespace and also if the string contains a single 'c' it stops matching so sub-string matches are impossible: [example](https://regex101.com/r/FKcWCr/1) | [example with ^$ removed](https://regex101.com/r/bULzR5/1)